# Toggle hot corners with a script

Tags: terminal

Hallo I am annoyed that hot corners won't be disabled when I am playing a fullscreen game. So I want a quick way to toggle the settings. I found this command

```
defaults write com.apple.dock wvous-tl-corner -int 1
```

Unfortunately it doesn't change anything.
What can I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`wvous-tl-corner` is the top-left hot corner. Use ‘tl’, ‘tr’, ‘bl’, ‘br’ for each corner respectively, and use `-int 0` to disable that corner.

To find the integer for activating the hot corner of choice, make the change in System Preferences, then use `defaults read com.apple.dock wvous-tl-corner`.

Don't forget to restart the Dock too after writing using defaults: `killall Dock`.

Comment: the killall Dock command was the missing part. thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can first figure out your existing values by running these in the terminal one by one

```
defaults read com.apple.dock "wvous-tl-corner"
defaults read com.apple.dock "wvous-tr-corner"
defaults read com.apple.dock "wvous-bl-corner"
defaults read com.apple.dock "wvous-br-corner"
```

Then create a new file and call it something like toggle-hot-corners.sh
make sure to make it executable with

```
chmod +x toggle-hot-corners.sh
```

Then add this code and add your specific values in the **enable_hot_corners**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -eu

function disable_hot_corners(){
  defaults write com.apple.dock "wvous-tl-corner" -int 0
  defaults write com.apple.dock "wvous-tr-corner" -int 0
  defaults write com.apple.dock "wvous-br-corner" -int 0
  defaults write com.apple.dock "wvous-bl-corner" -int 0
}

function enable_hot_corners(){
  defaults write com.apple.dock "wvous-tl-corner" -int 2
  defaults write com.apple.dock "wvous-tr-corner" -int 3
  defaults write com.apple.dock "wvous-bl-corner" -int 11
  defaults write com.apple.dock "wvous-br-corner" -int 4
}

# Make sure to read from a corner that has an active value > 0
has_hot_corners=$(defaults read com.apple.dock "wvous-tl-corner")

# Toggle
if (( $has_hot_corners != 0 ))
then
  disable_hot_corners
else
  enable_hot_corners
fi

# Restart Dock
killall Dock
```

Double click the file or run it from the terminal with `./toggle-hot-corners.sh` from the directory you added it to.

| Preference | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Disabled | 0 |
| Nothing | 1 |
| Mission Control | 2 |
| Application Windows | 3 |
| Desktop | 4 |
| Start Screensaver | 5 |
| Disable Screensaver | 6 |
| Puts Display to Sleep | 10 |
| Launchpad | 11 |
| Notification Center | 12 |
| Lock Screen | 13 |
| Quick Note | 14 |

Answer (score 2):

Riffing on the [excellent answer from @grg](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/300697/89456), you can loop over each corner like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -eu

# Turn off hot-corners
for corner in tl tr br bl;
  do
    defaults write com.apple.dock "wvous-$corner-corner" -int 0
  done
killall Dock
```

Comment: What does the `set -eu` do?

Comment: @Casimir it makes the shell script quit immediately in case of error. `-e` means "Exit immediately if a command exits with a non-zero status". `-u` means "Treat unset variables as an error when substituting". The script will still work without it, but many people consider it a best practice to include it at the top of every shell script, since it makes it more likely you will catch bugs.